# how to apply two functions to a li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three li and two functions I got that by clicking on each of them changes to white, however I want to click on one of the three the other two return to the original color.

```js
function whitecolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', 'white');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

function graycolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', '#F2F2F2');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

$("#op1").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  graycolor(evt.target);
});

$("#op2").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  graycolor(evt.target);
});

$("#op3").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  graycolor(evt.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="" id="op1" name="op1">aaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op2" name="op2">bbb</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op3" name="op3">ccc</a></li>
```

I want that if I click on op2 the op1 get the characteristics of the function `whitecolor`.

Comment: Consider using CSS classes to define the CSS so that all you have to do is use `toggleClass`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to restore all the links  calling the `whitecolor()` function on all, and then apply the `graycolor()` function only to the target one.

```js
function whitecolor(elem)
{
  $(elem).css('background-color', 'white');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

function graycolor(elem)
{
  $(elem).css('background-color', '#F2F2F2');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

$("#op1, #op2, #op3").click(function(evt)
{
  evt.preventDefault();
  whitecolor("#op1, #op2, #op3");
  graycolor(evt.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li><a href="" id="op1" name="op1">aaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op2" name="op2">bbb</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op3" name="op3">ccc</a></li>
```

Comment: Can I have an explanation for the down-vote, So I can delete this if not useful. Actually all the other answers presents the same effect to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest applying the white styles to all elements, then on top of that apply the gray style to the clicked element.

I would prefer to use a class, but for this example I'm just targeting the elements with type selectors so that I don't need to touch your markup.

I also removed some unnecessary duplication: since the body of all three click handlers are identical, you can just use the same anonymous function as the click handler for all three elements, comma-separated.

```js
function whitecolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', 'white');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

function graycolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', '#F2F2F2');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

$("#op1,#op2,#op3").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  whitecolor($('a'));
  graycolor(evt.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="" id="op1" name="op1">aaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op2" name="op2">bbb</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op3" name="op3">ccc</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating essentially the same code for three separate elements, consider using the same classname on the elements and writing your code to act on the whole group at once.

It's also much simpler to toggle classnames than to modify the style rules individually (especially given that several of the rules you're touching don't actually change).

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
  $('.item').removeClass('gray') // resets all the elements to white
  $(this).addClass('gray') // sets the clicked element to gray
});
```

```css
/* set the default background color here so you don't need to toggle two classes. 
   Also set the borders here since those don't change at all */
.item {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #8C8A8A;
  border-right: 1px solid #8C8A8A;
}

/* Give the gray rule more specificity, so it'll override the default */
.item.gray {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="op1" class="item" name="op1">aaaa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="op2" class="item" name="op2">bbb</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="op3" class="item" name="op3">ccc</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the cleanest way to do this is by using css classes, but if you insist on using javascript then this would be your solution.

I even edited your white function to remove the borders

```js
function whitecolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', 'white');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '');
}

function graycolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', '#F2F2F2');
  $(elem).css('border-top', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
  $(elem).css('border-right', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

$("#op1").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  graycolor(evt.target);
  whitecolor($('#op2'));
  whitecolor($('#op3'));
});

$("#op2").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  graycolor(evt.target);
  whitecolor($('#op1'));
  whitecolor($('#op3'));
});

$("#op3").click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  graycolor(evt.target);
  whitecolor($('#op2'));
  whitecolor($('#op1'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<li><a href="" id="op1" name="op1">aaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op2" name="op2">bbb</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op3" name="op3">ccc</a></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **reset the colors for the other elements** before setting the clicked element to grey.

Also, you can shorten your code by applying the same logic to all your elements with the help of `forEach`, executed on an array of ids.

Finally, you need to run your `whitecolor` function once at the beginning to apply the style to all elements.

```js
function whitecolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', 'white');
  $(elem).css('border', '0px');
}

function graycolor(elem) {
  $(elem).css('background-color', '#F2F2F2');
  $(elem).css('border', '0.1px solid #8c8a8a');
}

const elems = ['#op1', '#op2', '#op3'];
elems.forEach(elem => {
  whitecolor(elem);
  $(elem).click(evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    elems.forEach(e => whitecolor(e));
    graycolor(evt.target);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" id="op1" name="op1">aaaa</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op2" name="op2">bbb</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="op3" name="op3">ccc</a></li>
```